# Background notifications while app is killed on Android O+

Tags: android

I'd like to send notifications while my application is closed or killed.
I've read that since Android O the background services are garbage collected when applications are wiped out from recent applications.
My application behaves this way: when the user opens the application, some alarms are set to send notifications later. If the application is open or in the background, he will receive notifications. I'm using an [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)
But when the application is closed or killed, the AlarmManager is closed as well.
I've tried to use a Service and a BroadcastReceiver but not of them wake up or stay alive to make it.

With Android versions older than Android Oreo, this is working as the background services stay alive.

I am wondering if we can do this feature of scheduled notifications after Android O

Answer (score 0):

If may work with O, but starting from Q, you can't start an activity from background service anymore, you need to start foreground service to be able to keep the app active when alarm arrives, something like this:

```
Intent foregroundAlarmService = new Intent(context, ForegroundAlarmService.class);
context.startForegroundService(foregroundAlarmService);
```

Comment: What should ForegroundAlarmService derive from?

Comment: ForegroundAlarmService extends Service

Comment: The service still seems to be killed when the app is killed on Android Q

Comment: Service can be killed, but if you can use silent push notification to restart it.